# Why isn't str_count working with multiple strings?

Tags: r, string, substr-count

I have a string with text like this:

```
Text <- c("How are you","What is your name","Hi my name is","You ate your cake")
```

And I want an output that counts the number of times the word "you" or "your" appears

```
Text                   NumYou
"How are you"          1
"What is your name"    1
"Hi my name is"        0
"You ate your cake"    2
```

I tried using the str_count function but it was missing occurrences of "you" and "your"

```
NumYou = str_count(text,c("you","your"))
```

Why isn't str_count working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `pattern` as one string.

```
stringr::str_count(tolower(Text),'you|your')
#[1] 1 1 0 2
```